# Javascript alert event between pages

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two php rendered pages: customer invoices and customer management.
My users have the need to quickly create a customer from within the customer invoices page.

I do not want to add extra code to the customer invoices page to provide that functionality, i'd rather that the code opens a second tab and shows the customer management page.

Once the user created a new customer, that page should close and the number of the customer that was created needs to be filled in the customer input field which is on the customer invoices page.

Does anyone know if there any other way than using websockets or node.js, preferably with vanilla javascript (or jQuery), to make this work? Google isn't helping me much..

Answer (score 0):

You can try to insert the customer management page as a iframe overlay via JS - this is much more user-friendly as a new tab.

After user saves his customer record and a customer number is generated (all within the iframe), pass the customer number with JS to the parent-page:

```
<script>
  parent.document.getElementById('customer_number_input').value = '12346789';
  // after that close iframe overlay if needed
  parent.document.getElementById('customer_management_iframe').remove();
</script>
```

Comment: "*this is much more user-friendly as a new tab*" - *than* a new tab?